# Getting RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread' when trying to access event loop after asyncio.run()

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

On trying to run below snippet of code getting `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.`

```
import asyncio

async def task():
    print("executing task")

def main():
    asyncio.run(task())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What is the reason behind this, is this because `asyncio.run()` is creating a temporary event loop and closing it ? Is there reference to this behaviour in the official documentation ?

Comment: Your title is misleading.  The call to asyncio.run works fine.  The error is raised by the SECOND line of code in main():  `asyncio.get_event_loop()`.  That's if you're running V3.11; starting with Python3.11 it became an error to call this function if there is no currently running loop.  There is documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop.  but in my opinion it is not adequate.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Fixed the title now. Can you explain the reason (or the why?) behind the error ?

Comment: I thought I already did.  The error means exactly what it says: you have no running event loop.  The run() method has already closed the event loop that it created.  If you want to call loop.run_forever, the previous line should be `loop=asyncio.new_event_loop()`.  But it's better to just call run() to create your first task, otherwise your program never returns from loop.run_forever.